# mapping over items in ajax call react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am making an ajax call to google fonts api and receiving a list of items from there. I am calling my ajax call inside of my componentDidMount method.

I later have a method that renders a field of options for my fonts that I have received from my ajax request. I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(URL)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data" + data);
        this.setState({
          googleFonts: data
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({
          errors: err
        })
      })
  }
```

here is where I render my options

```
 renderFonts() {

    let data = this.state.googleFonts.data.items;
    return data.map((font, index) => {
      return (
        <option>{font.family}</option>
      )
    })
  }
```

here is where I call my method that returns the options

```
<FormControl
                    style={inputFieldStyle}
                    componentClass="select"
                    placeholder="select"

                  >

                    {this.renderFonts()}

                  </FormControl>
```

the error that I am getting is that data is undefined specifically this.state.googleFonts.data.items. I think it has to do with a race condition of my componentDidMount ajax call and the method being called before that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just noticed another potential problem in your code. Can you `console.log(this.state)` at the beginning of `renderFonts`. What does it print?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access a property that has not been asynchronously fetched yet and getting a `Cannot read property of undefined` error.

At the very beginning of your `renderFonts` method, you can add this line:

```
if (!this.state.googleFonts) return null;
```

This way, you will not attempt to access properties of `this.state.googleFonts` before it is defined. After the API call is resolved, the component will be rerendered with the correct values.

Your other option would be to use lodash `_.get` which returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error when you attempt to access a property of `undefined`.